Derive formula in formal arithmetic from axioms
I have formal arithmetic with these non-logical axioms:
$
\begin{align*}
A_{x0} &: \quad \forall x \, (x \times 0 = 0) \\
A_{x_s} &: \quad \forall x \, \forall y \, (x \times s(y) = x \times y + x) \\
A_{+0} &: \quad \forall x \, (x + 0 = x) \\
A_{+s} &: \quad \forall x \, \forall y \, (x + s(y) = s(x + y)) \\
A_{r=} &: \quad \forall x \, (x = x) \\
A_{s=} &: \quad \forall x \, \forall y \, ((x = y) \rightarrow (y = x)) \\
A_{t=} &: \quad \forall x \, \forall y \, \forall z \, ((x = y) \rightarrow (x = z) \rightarrow (y = z)) \\
A_{+=s} &: \quad \forall x \, \forall y \, ((x = y) \rightarrow (s(x) = s(y))) \\
A_{-=s} &: \quad \forall x \, \forall y \, ((s(x) = s(y)) \rightarrow (x = y)) \\
A_0 &: \quad \forall x \, \neg (0 = s(x)) \\
A_{\text{ind}} &: \quad \varphi \{x/0\} \land \forall x \, (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi \{x/s(x)\}) \rightarrow \forall x \, \varphi
\end{align*}
$
Is there any way to get formula $x \times y = 0 \rightarrow x = 0 \vee y = 0 $ from axioms (to derive from the axioms, I also can use predicate axioms and classic axioms)? I think i need to use axiom of induction for x and y, but I'm not sure how  to procced with this ...

@MauroALLEGRANZA can i do it like this : prove formula $\phi(x)=\forall y (x \times y = 0 \rightarrow x = 0 \vee y = 0)$ - and prove $\forall x \phi(x)$ ? (by induction)

First, prove that everything is either $0$ or a successor: $\forall x\,(x=0\lor \exists x'\, (x=s(x')))$. This is essentially immediate from the induction axiom.
Now suppose $x\times y=0$ and assume for contradiction that $x\neq 0$ and $y\neq 0$. Then there exist $x'$ and $y'$ such that $x=s(x')$ and $y=s(y')$.
Then $0=s(x')\times s(y')=s(x')\times y'+s(x')=s(s(x')\times y'+x')$, contradicting $A_0$.

Consider a number $a$ whatever and use Induction on $y$.
The result will be $\forall y [a \times y=0 \to (a=0 \lor y=0)]$.
But $a$ is a variable whatever: thus, we can apply Generalization to conclude with $\forall x \forall y [ \ldots]$.
Base step: $y=0$, therefore $x=0 \lor y=0$.
For the Induction step you have to use the preliminary result: $a\ne 0 \to (a \times b=0 \to b=0)$.
Assuming that formula holds for $y$, we assume that $a \times s(y)=0$. But $s(y) \ne 0$: therefore $x=0$ and thus $x =0 \lor s(y)=0$.

sorry, i don't understand what's induction step here .. is it the part - $\forall x , (\varphi \rightarrow \varphi {x/s(x)})$ ?

i feel like the derivation of the induction step will be very long if we use only axioms ... can you please give another hint?
